# Counting records from another mysql table with a left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two DB tables, one that store events and the second that stores any associated comments for that event.

DB Tables:

```
events: id, owner_id, timestamp
comments: cmt_id, parent_id(events id), cmt_time
```

I'm trying to get the last 5 comments for each event based on a specific owner_id.

This is how I'm joining my tables:

```
SELECT * FROM `events` 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.parent_id=events.id 
WHERE owner_id=X     
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Any idea how I can get the number of comments based on the event_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about the number of comments for each event (at least as I interpret it).  For this, you want to use a `group by`:

```
SELECT e.event_id, COUNT(c.parent_id) as NumComments
FROM events e left JOIN
     comments c
     ON c.parent_id=e.id 
WHERE e.owner_id = X     
group by e.event_id;
```

As for the query in your question.  It does not do what you want it to do ("I'm trying to get the last 5 comments for each event based on a specific owner_id.").  Instead, it is getting the last five comments for a given user.  Period.

Comment: This works...I added: GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY e.timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 0, 5 to the end it it does grab what I need.  I don't think I made it clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the table join at then use the COUNT() function to count how many comments are associated with a given event_id

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

I would give an example but I'm not entirely sure what you would like your end dataset to look like. COUNT(col) will count the number of rows associated with the query result

Comment: Ideally I need the number of comments for each event. I could make a seperate call for each event but I was hoping to do it with just one DB call